Hide clear button on input type
I want my input not gets cleared as I always need it my api. I need to disable input date type clear button.
I tried it using CSS and tailwind CSS to disable this clear button date calender using input
enter image description here
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
      addUtilities({
        ".disable-clear::-webkit-clear-button": {
          display: "none",
        },
        ".disable-clear::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator": {
          opacity: "1 !important",
        },
      });
    }),
  ],
};

                <input
                type="date"
                value={startDate || ""}
                min={getMinStartDate(endDate)}
                max={endDate}
                onChange={handleStartDateChange}
                className="px-3 py-1 border rounded-lg shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-yellow-300 disable-clear"
                placeholder="Start Date"
              />`


I don't think you can, this looks like the default browser datepicker.
